# Converting double array values to char values in C++

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, double

I have a matrix array of doubles that I need to store into an array of chars. These 32-bit double values are guaranteed to be small enough to fit into an 8-bit char value. (The maximum double value in my program is 31). I've researched a bit and what I find are solutions to store a double as a char*, in other words convert a double to a c_string. This is NOT what I seek to achieve.

```
// I'm dealing with a 15*4 double array
double **d_array = new double*[15];
d_array[i] = new double[4];

// This creates a char array (That will have > 15*4 spaces)
unsigned char *c_array = new unsigned char [1024];
```

I can iterate a loop over the double matrix to store to the character matrix.
Say I had d_array[1][0] = 4. I want to have c_array[5] = 4. Because 4 is 00000100, it should be able to fit.

Comment: To clarify, the values stored in d_array are non-negative and at most = 31.

Comment: You can just assign the values, it will truncate. ie: `c_array[5] = d_array[1][0];`

Comment: @RichardCritten This will generate a compiler warning though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just make the assignment in your loop and it will automatically be truncated and converted (you may get a compiler warning):

```
c_array[0] = d_array[0][0];

To be safe, you could do

c_array[0] = (char)(int)d_array[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `uint8_t` since a `char` is either signed, unsigned or `char`.

You can use `static_cast`:

```
uint8_t value = static_cast<uint8_t>(d_array[i][j]);
```

If you want to *copy* the bytes of a floating point to a buffer:

```
uint8_t buffer[4096];
float f_value = 3.14;
uint8_t * p_float = static_cast<uint8_t *>(&f_value);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i)
{
  buffer[index + i] = p_float[i];
}
```